# Should UI project type be considered in domain model implementation?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, dns, design-patterns

Hmm, the question is in title :). Just some thoughts about the problem...

I'm thinking of domain models of my application. I've found that State pattern suits me well as I have Business object that changed its state and states have strict order, also there are number of operations which logic is depends on State. 
However I know that my UI will be web application. As web applications is stateless (in its general implementation) then State will be changed only one time and I won't have all benefits of state pattern. I even don't need to change StateObject in someAction in such web scenario.

So maybe it will be better just to create rules of states order and don't use State pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your domain layer shouldn't be aware of your UI layer. Domain objects should be created to be UI-agnostic. That's not to say that a domain object can't be set up in a way to work with UI; it depends on the project, and is something I'm dealing with now.